# Validar una Expresión regular en javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

*Como puedo validar una expresión regular en javaScript*

Tengo esta validación en `javaScript`

```
if ($("#nombre").val() == (/[A-Za-z0-9-\s+@+.+-]/)) {
     alert('No puedes ingresar caracteres especiales');
}
```

*Bueno eso es lo que estoy tratando de realizar*

***Como puedo lograr comparar caracteres especiales en `javaScript`***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el RegExp; `test()` y este formato /[`!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};':"\|,.<>/?~]/ para caracteres especiales.

```js
const formato = /[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;

const pruebaTexto = (texto) => {
  if (formato.test(texto)) {
    console.log('No puedes ingresar caracteres especiales');
  } else {
    console.log(texto);
  }
}

pruebaTexto('Hola!');
pruebaTexto('Hola c@mo estas??');
pruebaTexto('Nada empanada');
```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que esa expresión esta mala para empezar. Para validar un correo electrónico por ejemplo puede hacer algo como esto:

```
let email='correo@correo.com';

    let reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;

if ((email.match(reg))) {
//Es un correo efectivamente...

}
```

Ahí ya lo que quedaría es buscar la expresión regular correcta